# inserting variables into php echo of a submit button

Tags: php

Hi I'm looking to insert a varible into a submit buttons name when I echo it via a loop so that each button has a unique name

```
   $x=0;
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM userstats ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5; ";
            $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
            echo ("<table>");
            echo ("<tr>");
            echo ("<th>Name</th>");
            echo ("<th>Level</th>");
            echo ("<th>Stats</th>");
            echo ("<th>Win Chance</th>");
            echo ("<th>Action</th>");
            echo ("</tr>");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                if($row['username'] !== $_SESSION['username']){//add so it dosent put duplicates
                    echo("<tr>");
                    echo("<th>".$row['username']." </th>");
                    echo("<th>Level: ".$row['Level']." </th>");
                    echo("<th>Player Stats:".$row['Attack']."/".$row['Defence']." </th>");
                    echo("<th>Win Chance: ");
                    echo(CalculateWinChance($link,$row['Defence']));
                    echo("<input type='hidden' name='".$x."hidden1' value='".$row['Defence']."' />");
                    echo("<input type='hidden' name='".$x."hidden2' value='".$row['username']."' />");
                    echo("<th><input type='submit' name = 'Attack_Btn".$x."' onclick = 'BattlePlayers()' value ='Attack'></th>");
                    echo("</tr>");
                    $x=$x+1;
                }
            }
            echo ("</table>");
```

I tried the above code but it does not change the name attribute? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: post the complete code ... where is $x assigned?

Comment: Maybe `$x` is empty and please use better names for your variables.

Comment: ive updated the post with all of the code

Comment: what does the `CalculateWinChance()` function do, or do you feel it's not relevant to the question/problem? and did you start the session? Check for errors via PHP and MySQL, run a var_dump and look at your HTML source.

Comment: why the ajax tag?

Comment: other function is not relevant. code works fine without the $x it just has no way to determine which button you pressed to it always sends the last hidden values instead of the specific on for that row. i checked the html source before posting and all the buttons names are just Attack_Btn

Comment: i know my variables names are awful its just for testing purposes atm

Comment: then as @PhiterFernandes already stated.... so check that. However, more often than none, people say that unknown/unposted code is not relevant, is known at the end of countless comments to be the source or part of the problem.

Comment: echo the $x right before the line with $x=$x+1; to see if there are values

Comment: Since you say that the added function is irrelevant, I have removed the `ajax` tag from your question since there is no code to support the question. You can add it back in when you have posted it.

Comment: `$x == 0` and it's your problem?

Comment: $ is not empty its prining as expected 01234

Comment: is just does not seem to be added to the name

Comment: *"$ is not empty its prining as expected 01234"* - The leading zero is treated as an octal, that's why it's failing.

Comment: thank you very much that solved it :) what is an octal ?

Comment: @GregHBushnell you're welcome. Here http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Comment: you can put that as an answer can ill accept it :)

Comment: @GregHBushnell I'm glad to have been able to provide a solution. After seeing your comment about that leading zero, was the clincher here ;-) *Cheers*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *you can put that as an answer can ill accept it :) – GregHBushnell*

Posting from comments:

> *"$ is not empty its prining as expected 01234" - The leading zero is treated as an octal, that's why it's failing. . – Fred -ii*
>
> *thank you very much that solved it :) what is an octal ? – GregHBushnell*

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal

---

**Footnote:**

`echo` is a language construct and not a "function" per se. So, you can safely omit all of the `()`, since that's just more code than needed really.

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php